# (C++) Total number of elements in a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I've learned that checking the sizes of one-dimensional vectors is an easy task, because one can just write

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    vector <int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    cout << sizeof(v)/sizeof(int) << endl;
}
```

The output is, as expected, 4.

However, when I try the same approach with a multidimensional vector, the results are not what I would count as correct:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    vector <vector<int>> v = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5}}; // 5 elements in total
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    cout << sizeof(v)/sizeof(int) << endl;
}
```

This time, the output is 3 instead of the expected 5. Can somebody please explain why this happens, and how to modify the code so that it produces the correct output?

Comment: `sizeof` of a vector doesn't actually do what you think it does. Fun fact: your `sizeof(v)` will ***always*** give you the same value whether it's completely empty or contains more `int`s than there are atoms in this universe.

Comment: *The output is, as expected, 4* -- [No, not here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09039f9f458f2d31).  As you can see, the output is 6 for the `sizeof` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your 2nd example, `v` is a vector of `vector<int>`s, so `v.size()` reports 3 **sub-vectors** instead of the number of integers.

`std::vector::size()` **does not recurse**, you have to do this yourself:

```cpp
std::size_t sum = 0;
for (auto &&i : v) {
    sum += i.size();
}
// return sum;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can write a helper function to calculate the size recursively on *multi-dimensional vector*s.

```
template <typename T>
size_t get_size(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    return v.size();
}
template <typename T>
size_t get_size(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v) {
    size_t size = 0;
    for (const auto& vv : v) {
        size += get_size(vv); // get the size recursively
    }
    return size;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eUlYh1dDwy28S22O)

BTW: `sizeof` gives size of object representation of type, which is determined at compile-time. So what `sizeof(v)` returns has nothing to do with the number of elements of `v`, which might not be what you want.